# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf

I know this question has been asked a number of times on the site, however I've tried to follow the advice given but am getting nowhere.

I have a method which is called from a separate thread which simply adds a TextBlock to a stackpanel on the GUI. However no matter how I try to implement this I keep getting the error: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

Apologies if this is a very simple question, however I'm brand new to WPF....

```
private void AddTbToStackPanel(string text)
    {
        StackPanel stackPanel = stackPanel1 as StackPanel;
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = text;            
        stackPanel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { stackPanel.Children.Add(tb); }));
    }
```

Comment: is there any reason you have delegated altering the UI element to a child thread? Why cant it be done in the main thread based on the result you get from the child thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the textblock in the worker thread.

Move the `new TextBlock()` into the lambda.

```
stackPanel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
     () => { stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = text }); }));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just figured it out - I need to use Dispatcher on all the objects as below:

```
private void AddTbToStackPanel(string text)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
        {
            StackPanel stackPanel = stackPanel1 as StackPanel;
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = text;                
            stackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void AddTbToStackPanel(string text)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => {
            StackPanel stackPanel = stackPanel1 as StackPanel;
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = text;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample which may help you implementing the task and UI Updates. You can easily convert the following sample to you scenario.
You can have a look at my blog which has detailed Explanation regarding this error and solution

http://bathinenivenkatesh.blogspot.com/2011/07/wpf-build-more-responsive-ui.html

```
ObservableCollection images = new ObservableCollection(); 
TaskFactory tFactory = new TaskFactory(); 
tFactory.StartNew(() => 
{ 
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{ 
//GET IMAGE Path FROM SERVER 
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() 
{ 
// UPDATE PROGRESS BAR IN UI 
}); 

images.Add((""); 
} 

}).ContinueWith(t => 
{ 
if (t.IsFaulted) 
{ 
// EXCEPTION IF THREAD IS FAULT 
throw t.Exception; 
} 
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() 
{ 
//PROCESS IMAGES AND DISPLAY 
}); 
});
```

Comment: Why not let ContinueWith run on the UI thread instead? .ContinueWith(t => ..., TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())

Comment: Agree with you we can either use  "TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously" along with continue with..